# Template level constant

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm used to declare ui element selectors, when I'm implementing UI module in ASP.NET.
It goes something like this:

```
...
var loginSelector = '#btnLogin';
var textBoxSelector = 'form.login[type=text]';
...
$(textBoxSelector).val('');
...
```

That way I have only one place to change if html got updated.
How can declare template level constants in Meteor, to used across all template helpers and events? What are the best practices for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want template-level scope you can simply declare these in the same file as your template helpers and events. They will be available in all your helpers and events. If you want a wider scope then you can create global variables.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I was sure that variables declared at the file would be global-wide.

Comment: If you declare them with `var` then file-scope.